# Adding an if statement to a for loop

Tags: javascript

Hey i have a school project I am working on, and I am curious on how to add if statements inside of a for loop.  My code asks the user to input the number of pets they have, and I want to put it into a list.  I am able to make the list, but I would like to add the word "and" if the user puts two words, and commas if the user enters 3 or more into the list.  Currently I am trying to compile it all together but I am getting errors in my code.

```
//For loop for pet names
    var Petlist = "";
    for (cntr = 1; cntr <= parseInt(petnum); cntr++)
    {
    petID = 'pet' + cntr;
    PetName = $(petID).value + ' ';
    Petlist += PetName;
    }
```

Currently it will put it all together in a string like "Spot Doug Fido" but I would like to put it into a string like "Spot, Doug, Fido".  Similarly I would like two names to be listed as "Spot and Fido" instead of "Spot Fido" like it would be now.

Comment: Instead of adding each name to a string, `.push()` each name to an empty array. Then, if the length of your array after your `for` loop is equal to `2`, you can do `.join(' and ')`, which will join all your elements in your array into a string with `and` separating each element. If the length is greater than `2` you can `.join(', ')`, which will join each element into a string, separating each element with a comma

Comment: `Petlist += PetName;` is where you would push into an array. Then outside of the loop do what @NickParsons suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Split your string on spaces, then check result array length and return built result.

```js
const list1 = "Spot";
const list2 = "Spot Doug"
const list3 = "Spot Doug Fido"

const splitAndJoin = string => {
  const stringArray = string.split(" ");

  switch (stringArray.length) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      return string; // original string

    case 2:
      return stringArray.join(' and ');

    default:
      return stringArray.join(', ');
  }
}

console.log(splitAndJoin(list1)); // Spot
console.log(splitAndJoin(list2)); // Spot and Doug
console.log(splitAndJoin(list3)); // Spot, Doug, Fido
```